# Proving the relationship between left and right eigenvalues for a complex generalized eigenproblem

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, generalized-eigenvector

A generalized right eigenproblem is defined as:

$A q = \lambda B q$

where $A$ and $B$ are complex matrices in general and $q$ represents the right eigenvector, which is a column vector, and $\lambda$ is the scalar right eigenvalue.

The generalised left eigenproblem for the same $A$ and $B$ matrices is:

$v A = \kappa v B$

where $v$ represents the left eigenvector, which is a row vector, and $\kappa$ is the scalar left eigenvalue. Let's assume that $\kappa \neq \lambda$ in general for now.

**How do we prove that $\kappa = \lambda^*$, where the asterisk represents the complex conjugate operation?**

I can construct one way:

1. Left-multiply the right eigenproblem with $v$ to make: $vAq = \lambda v B q$.
2. Right-multiply the left eigenproblem with $q$ to make: $vAq = \kappa vBq$.
3. By comparing the two resultant equations, we conclude that either $\lambda = \kappa$ or $vAq = 0$.

Clearly, this conclusion is not correct if $A, B, v, q$ can be complex in general.

Another way might be to use the conjugate transpose operation denoted by $H$.

1. Take the conjugate transpose of the left eigenproblem to make: $A^H v^H = \kappa^* B^H v^H$
2. ...?

Comment: Why do you think your generalised left eigenvalues are the complex conjugates of your generalised right eigenvalues?  This is *not* true in general.  If the matrices $\ A\ $ and $\  B\ $ are square, then the set of generalised left eigenvalues will be the *same* as the set of generalised right eigenvalues, not the set of their complex conjugates.

Comment: Yes, let's say that $A$ and $B$ are square matrices. We can define a slightly different eigenproblem: $A^H y = \alpha B^H y$, where $\alpha$ is the eigenvalue and $y$ is the right eigenvector. Taking the conjugate transpose of that eigenproblem yields: $y^H A = \alpha^* y^H B$. Based on the similarity between this and the left eigenproblem defined above, I reason that there must be some way to connect the right eigenproblem to this equation that involves a complex conjugate.

Comment: This is related to the adjoint eigenproblem

Comment: Yes, your equations tell you that  $\ \alpha\ $ is a right  eigenvalue for the matrix pair $\ A^H, B^H\ $ if and only if $\ \alpha^*\ $ is a left eigenvalue (of the same geometric multiplicity) for the matrix pair $\ A,B\ $.

Comment: I have developed a more thorough elaboration and proof but I was unable to fit it in a comment. Perhaps you could take a look! The link is https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4483439/what-is-the-connection-between-the-adjoint-and-left-right-generalized-eigenprobl